# Add arraylist to arraylist, using stream API

Tags: java, collections, stream

Have a method, that generate ArrayList:

```
List<Entity> method (String s){
    ........
    return list;
}
```

How to collect List from List collection, using stream API?
(similar to newList.addAll(list);

```
List<String> stringList = someGenerateStrings();

List<Entity> newList = stringList.stream()
    .map(this::method)
    .collect(?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to flatten your stream of lists into a stream of list elements.  You can use [`Stream`'s `flatMap` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

This basically takes the elements out of the inner `Stream`s you create and into the main `Stream`.

```
.flatMap(p -> method(p).stream())
```

Then it's as simple as collecting to a `List`.

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```